# What will be the GPath expression for Rest Assured

Tags: rest-assured, gpath

I have tried to create GPath expression with filter criteria to return `"my-notes"` in list of object when '"my-type"' is SPECIAL

like : '"data.my-node.nodes.findAll{it.'my-type'=='GENERAL'}.'my-nodes'"'

but unable to get response from the below json

```
{
   "data": {"my-node":    [
            {
         "nodes": [         {
            "my-nodes": [{"my-note": "abcdefg"}],
            "my-type": "GENERAL"
         }],
         "my-instruction": null
      },
            {
         "nodes": [         {
            "my-nodes": [{"my-note": "abcdefg"}],
            "my-type": "SPECIAL"
         }],
         "my-instruction": null
      },
            {
         "nodes": [         {
            "my-nodes": [{"my-note": "oiugitoirtuhou"}],
            "my-type": "SPECIAL"
         }],
         "my-instruction": null
      },
            {
         "nodes": [         {
            "my-nodes": [{"my-note": "ifuoirjhihj"}],
            "my-type": "SPECIAL"
         }],
         "my-instruction": null
      },
            {
         "nodes": [         {
            "my-nodes": [{"my-note": "idfgdiufgdhsfuihdf"}],
            "my-type": "SPECIAL"
         }],
         "my-instruction": null
      },
            {
         "nodes": [         {
            "my-nodes": [{"my-note": "iydfgsigdfgdgidsf"}],
            "my-type": "SPECIAL"
         }],
         "my-instruction": null
      }
   ]}
}
```

Comment: Use JsonPath jayway will save your time and effort. `$..my-nodes` https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17 Thanks for your comments actually I want to know what I am doing wrong with GPath

Answer (score 0):

The GPath syntax is

```java
List<?> value = JsonPath.from(res).get("data['my-node'].nodes.flatten().findAll{it.'my-type'=='GENERAL'}['my-nodes'].flatten()");
System.out.println(value);
//[{my-note=abcdefg}]
```

- First, use `['key-abc']` for keys contain special characters.
- Second, use `flatten()` method to make 2D array to 1D array.